# Extract specific string via regex from textfile

Tags: regex, extract

I have a text file with a lot of content. I want to extract the following text fragments beginning with TXT_ and ending with a ).

e.g.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. (**TXT_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT_THIS**). At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. (**TXT_AND_THIS**) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Expected result:

- TXT_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT_THIS
- TXT_AND_THIS

I just the need the regex for the result.

Thank you so much for your help.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which language you are working. In R, for example, you can use `str_extract_all`:

```
 str_extract_all(txt, "TXT\\w+")
 [[1]]
 [1] "TXT_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT_THIS" "TXT_AND_THIS"
```

Even if you don't work in R, the pattern used in the solution will not change greatly; it is in fact simple: supposing that all target strings start with the same literal pattern, say "TXT", and only contain alphabetic characters and the underscore, the parts after "TXT" can conveniently be matched by `\\w+`, a character class for alphanumeric characters **and** the underscore.

```
txt <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. (TXT_I_WANT_TO_EXTRACT_THIS). At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. (TXT_AND_THIS) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
```